# Docker registry with Nexus : 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-registry

I want to use a Nexus as private registry to push docker image but I'm not able to login

When I try this :

```
docker login xxx.xxx.com:8500
```

I have this message :

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://xxx.xxx.com:8500/v2/ failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable
```

I set up my /etc/docker/daemon.json like this :

```
{
  "insecure-registries": [
    "xxx.xxx.com:8500",
    "xxx.xxx.com:8501"
  ]
}
```

And when I try this :

```
curl http://xxx.xxx.com:8500/v2/_catalog
```

I have a response :

```
{"repositories":[]}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using the HTTP port through a reverse proxy?  If not, try IP instead of .com address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with modifying the /etc/sysconfig/docker file. I added NO_PROXY="xxx.xxx.com" then exec "systemctl restart docker" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```
curl -i xxx.xxx.com:8500
```

In case it returns some output like the following log.

```bash
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 471
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Server: Jetty(9.4.43.v20210629)
```

The above log indicates that you have access to the Docker registry through cURL command.

So in order to solve your problem add `xxx.xxx.com:8500` to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` or `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-options.conf` with `insecure-registries` flag.

Then execute the following command in order to restart your docker.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```